# How to run laravel on ubuntu with lampp?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run laravel project with xampp on ubuntu 16.04. But I have a problem, I use port 8000 to run on folder laravel and  I can't connect to phymyadmin because database at localhost/phpmyadmin and laravel run on localhost:8000

Comment: so use a different port. There is a file called "configuration" in which you can set custom port number.

Comment: Your `localhost/phpmyadmin` will run on port 80 and laravel app will run on port 8000. There is no problem here. If you cannot connect with phpmyadmin, there is some other problem. Provide more information about the setup

Answer (score 1):

You can run your project on **php artisan serv --port=9000** , so your phpmyadmin run on localhost:8000 and your laravel project run on laravel:9000.

You can follow [this](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/282/running-phps-built-in-web-server) documents.